# Looking for a very simple RPG

Tags: new-players

I'm looking for a table-top RPG to host for people with no experience whatsoever.
I need something with simple, easy to use mechanics who encourage player's imagination when facing challenges, something that can help me involve the players in an interesting storyline.

When I say simple I mean:
little to no Stat sheet,
No complicated rules regarding taking actions
and Relatively few dice rolls.

The point should be making the players think of creative solutions while going through the story. Things like: how to get information from an npc, how to get out of an elaborate trap, how to get past a giant lava pool.

Of course the characters need to have some sort of abilities, even special ones, but using them shouldn't be complicated (like a wizard who's trying to build himself a strategy using a lot of different spells). Playing smart should be using everyone's unique abilities together.

Lastly, I'm planning on using this for one-shots of a couple of hours, not long campaigns.

TL:DR I need the simplest rpg to deliver a thrilling story for a group with no past experience, while making the players cooperate and find creative solutions to challenges.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: "Shopping" questions are off topic on Stack Exchange systems, generally, and this one in particular.  This kind of question has no one "best" answer, so doesn't fit well in this format.  There are lots of chat forums around for this kind of question.  Once you find a game, we're happy to help with "how to play" questions and "how to manage the game" questions and what not.

Comment: Specifically, in [this meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) we have a list of some forums you might like to check out, and the RPG Stack Exchange chat is quite welcoming and would probably enjoy discussing games that might fit your bill.